# Commerce Catalog Export & Import

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

When we install Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2, by default we got Habitat catalog. We have created a new catalog as per my project requirement. Now I want to deploy the same catalog to the other/higher environment, so we have exported our newly created catalog and imported the same package to the higher environment.

Here the problem is when I imported the newly created catalog, it removed the default catalog (Habitat catalog). I need the existing/default catalog as well. Please, can somebody help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Postman scripts in XC9.0.2, you have a *mode* parameter that is used to control how the import is processed. The two modes you can use are *Replace* and *Add*. This parameter is used in the *ImportCatalogsPrepareBlock*.

**Replace**: Causes the block to first execute the *IRemoveAllCatalogItemsPipeline*, before importing your catalog data.

**Add**: Imports your catalog data directly, without calling the *IRemoveAllCatalogItemsPipeline* first.

So if you call the controller and set the *mode* parameter to *add*, then your data will be appended to the data that already exists in the system. Note that if your import data contains Id's that already exist in the system then errors will be logged, there is also an error count threshold that is set and when that is met the import will stop and be marked as a failure.

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried but it is giving bad request error.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of import catalog is to remove all the catalogs and then import the new one. 
To import your new catalog as well as the Habitat catalog, make sure both are in the import folder. That should probably do the trick.

Best regards,
Erwin

Comment: Thanks for this trick. But want to know, is there any trick to import one catalog at a time without impacting existing one. Thanks again.

Comment: No, not with the default catalog import.